# how to display generic list in mvc view.It displays only one(last) record. I want all collection to be displayed

Tags: list, model-view-controller

I want to display a generic list in MVC view. This is my code:

```
var result = groupedData;

.ToDictionary(g => string.Format("{0}-{1:00}  {2}", g.Contract_Name,g.Year, g.Month),
               g => g.Count);

List<string> data = new List<string>(result.Keys); 

foreach (string value in data){
    records = value;
    Session["datas"] = records;
}
```

My view code is:

```
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black"><b>Contract Name</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black"><%: Session["datas"] %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It displays only one record. I want all collection to be displayed.

Comment: my view code is  <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="color:black"><b>Contract Name</b></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>                
                  <td style="color:black"><%: Session["datas"] %></td>                    
              </tr>
         </table>
        </div>           it displays only one records .i want all collection to be dispalyed

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are assigning the session variable one record at a time, each one overwriting the last. In order for this approach to work, you need to send the whole list and then iterate through it in your view, however, if you are using the MVC pattern you are supposed to use a view model that your controller sends to your view, and then you just access the Model property.

Are you sure that MVC is actually what you are using? This really doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: its is possible store list object in session and display list on view. is this other way to display  list in view

Comment: without session also print only one records